# Does Mac Notes always pull all notes from iCloud?

Tags: mac, icloud, notes.app

I've always tried keeping offline backups of all cloud services over the years, like my calendars, contacts, notes, etc.

With iCloud stuff, specifically Notes, it's not so easy - there is no export or backup option. I'm keeping my notes in iCloud, and synching seems to work great between my iPhone and Mac, but I want to regularly back everything up somewhere else.

Right now (in macOS 11.5.2) I'm just copying everything from /~/Library/Group Containers/group.com.apple.notes - this includes the SQLite database (kind of squirrelly, but it looks like it's all there), along with attachments and images as standalone files in a subdirectory. It seems to be complete.

My question is that is it guaranteed to be complete? If I create a note on my phone, and then open Notes on the Mac, it seems to be there right away. But since it's cloud-based, I'm wondering if the Mac will always sync, or if it ever does on-demand synching, which would mean my local directory wouldn't necessarily be complete.

Comment: I believe that notes does not do on-demand syncing. However, you could test this by turning off your internet and perusing your notes quickly. There is a spinner icon that appears when not fully syncronized.

Comment: @EzekielElin That's a good idea, I'll give that a try.